# Image is not uploading from angular to nodejs multer

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I am trying to upload an image from angular to nodejs using multer.But in nodejs i am getting image as 'undefined'. Since i am new to angular, may be small issue. I not getting proper output.

addbook.component.html

```
     <div class="mainContainer">
<div class='card'>
    <form (ngSubmit)="AddBook()">
<div class='card-header'>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Publish Your Book</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class='card-body'>            
  <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='table'>       
    
      <tbody>  
          
            <tr>
                <td><label>Book Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="book_name" [(ngModel)]="bookItem.bookName"/></td>                  
              </tr>  
              <tr>
                <td><label>Book Author</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="book_author" [(ngModel)]="bookItem.bookAuthor"/></td>                  
              </tr>  
              <tr>
                <td><label>Book Categories</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="book_category" [(ngModel)]="bookItem.bookCategory"/></td>                  
              </tr>  
              <tr>
                <td><label>Book Description</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="book_description" [(ngModel)]="bookItem.bookDescription"/></td>                  
              </tr>  
           <tr>

            <label class="image-upload-container btn btn-bwm">
              <span>Select Image</span>
              <input #imageInput
                     type="file"
                     accept="image/*"
                     (change)="upload($event)"
                     />
            </label>
           </tr>
      
              
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>                  
              </tr>             
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

addbook.component.ts

```
    export class AddbookComponent implements OnInit {
  title:String="Publish Your Book";
  constructor(private bookdataService: BookdataService,  private router: Router) { }
  bookItem= new BooksModel("","","","","");
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  AddBook()
  {
    
    this.bookdataService.newBook(this.bookItem);
    console.log("called");
    console.log(this.bookItem.bookImage);
    alert("Success");
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
 
  upload(event: any){

    const file=event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);  
    this.bookItem.bookImage=file;
  }

}
```

books.model

```
export class BooksModel{
   constructor(
       public bookName: string,
       public bookAuthor: string,
       public bookCategory: string,
       public bookDescription: string,
       public bookImage : string
   ){}
}
```

and this is my backend nodejs addbookRoutes.js where i have my multer working.

```
    const express=require(`express`);
const booksRouter=express.Router();
const Bookdata = require('../models/BookData');
const multer = require('multer');

const path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = './public/uploads';

  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    console.log("new: "+dir);
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  console.log("old: "+dir);

// set up multer for storing uploaded files
const storage=multer.diskStorage({
  //destination for files
  destination:function(request,file,callback){
    callback(null,'./public/uploads');
  },
  //add back the extensions
  filename:function(request,file, callback){
  
    callback(null,file.fieldname+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
})

//upload parameters for mutter
const upload = multer({ 
  storage: storage,
  limits:{
    fileSize: 1000000
  },
  fileFilter:function(req,file,callback){
    checkFileType(file, callback);
  }
});
//Check file type
function checkFileType(file, callback){

  // allowed extension
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  //check extension
  const extname=filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  //check mime
  const mimetype=filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if(mimetype&&extname){
    return callback(null, true);
  }else{
    callback('Error: Images only');
  }
}


console.log("in addBookRoutes");
  const cors = require('cors');
  var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
  
  booksRouter.use(cors());
  booksRouter.use(bodyparser.json());

  booksRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Bookdata.find()
            .then(function(books){
              console.log(books);
             
                res.send(books);
            })
  })    

  booksRouter.post('/insert',upload.single(`image`),function(req,res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE')
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
   
    var book = {       
       
        bookName : req.body.book.bookName,
        bookAuthor : req.body.book.bookAuthor,
        bookCategory : req.body.book.bookCategory,
        bookDescription : req.body.book.bookDescription,
        bookImage: {
          data: fs.readFileSync(path.join('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename)), 
          contentType: 'image/png',
              }
   }       
   var book = new Bookdata(book);
   book.save();
});
  module.exports=booksRouter;
```

nodejs model

```
const BookSchema=new Schema({
    bookId : Number,
    bookName : String,
    bookImage : {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
    bookAuthor : String,
    bookCategory : String,
    bookDescription : String

});

//Model creation
```

My angular service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import {BooksModel} from '../components/books/books.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookdataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
   getBooks(){
     return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/books");
   }
   newBook(item: BooksModel){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/books/insert",{"book": item})
    .subscribe(data =>{console.log(data)})
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi !
Please, read this, (attentively) : https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-file-upload-using-node-and-angular . If you're stuck, just reply :)

Comment: i am able to save all other fields except image :(

Comment: @RicardoMachado please do help, in my code there are models of angular form, here Formdata.. littlebit confused

Comment: 1st of all: can you use your upload service when you call it from POSTMAN or cURL? 2nd: your BookItem class is not a FormData class and thus will not add the image automatically. Please see the example of @RicardoMachado or others. Before you call your service you have to wrap your BookItem into FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The **event.target.files[0]** is not a string, but an Object describing the file that you want to upload.
2. Sending a JSON body with just the filename will not upload the file.
3. In the bookService you have to wrap the attributes of BookItem into a form. You can do it like this (assuming that bookImage is now the File object and not a string):

```
...
let uploadForm = new FormData();
Object.entries(bookItem).forEach(([key,value])=>{this.uploadForm.append(key, value)});
return this.http.post(url, this.uploadForm);
...
```

In your backend you have to receive a FORM with the POST request.

In the addBook section you have to replace the part

```
booksRouter.use(bodyparser.json());
```

with:

```
booksRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

and probably tinker a little bit with the request body to copy the correct results.

Comment: my form submit is calling AddBook() where i am calling my service

Comment: i want to bind all my form data into a model

Comment: Uploading a file from Angular requires a surrounding form when you send it. If you want to stick to JSON for your model you have to separate the uploading of the file from the rest of your model.

Comment: ok i understood...but i am not getting output..i not able to get result in nodejs

Comment: Did you test the backend function with postman or cURL? I would start with adjusting your nodejs code and test it with postman. If that works, then adjust your Angular code.

Comment: hi, now i am able to upload files in db. i have another doubt, if i have a form with two upload options..like one for cover image and another for pdf upload.. how will this work?

Comment: You can have multiple files in your upload request and they can be in different formats as well. The only thing you would have to do is to make sure you know which file is what.

Comment: ok one more doubt.. i have saved my file as binarydata in mongodb, how will i view it in angular?

Comment: That depends on your get function: it should define the content-type as "image/png" (if its a PNG that you're returning, otherwise GIF/JPG/...)

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612659/how-to-display-images-in-angular-from-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

In the change eventhandler I filtered the files and passed the accepted files and accepted names as separate formFields.

I set the formControl value to empty string when nothing is valid clearing the file list.

I set the formControl to an array of files for all accepted files ( setting an array instead of an empty string will go through and error handler telling you that you can only pass in an empty string for the file field just ignore that, the array will be accepted as value. You cannot change the original fileList)

When submitting be sure that you pass the array of files inside a FormData object under the same name as the name in multer fieldname.

Here is an example of a not nested formGroup:

```
      interface allowedType {
        allowedFiles: File[];
        allowedFileNames: string[];
      }

      maxSize = 8 * 1024000; // 8Mb to bytes.
      formatsAllowed = 'png,jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf,doc';

      form = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
        files: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        fileNames: new FormControl()
      });
      
      onFileChange(event) {
        const element = <HTMLInputElement>event.currentTarget;
        const fileList: FileList | null = element.files;
        let allowedFileNames: string; // comma separated allowed names list
        let allowedFiles: File[];

        if (fileList) {
          const allowed = this.filterFiles(fileList);
          allowedFileNames = allowed.allowedFileNames.toString();
          allowedFiles = allowed.allowedFiles;
        }

        // set value can only set strings or numbers not files it's been said
        // but you can set the array of files.  you will pass an error whe debugging that can be ignored
        // set it empty to clear the file list
        this.form.get('fileNames').setValue(allowedFileNames);
        if (!allowedFileNames) {
          this.form.controls['files'].setValue('');
        } else {
          this.form.controls['files'].setValue(allowedFiles);
        }
      }
      
       /**
       * filter only valid files
       * FileList is readonly and cannot be changed
       * you can only delete the entire file list by setting the value property of the input object to an empty string,
       */
      filterFiles(fileList: FileList): allowedType {
        const allowedFiles: File[] = [];
        const allowedFileNames: string[] = [];
        const fileExtRegExp: RegExp = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        const fileListArr = [...fileList];

        fileListArr.forEach(file => {
          const currentFileExt = fileExtRegExp.exec(file.name)[1].toLowerCase(); // file extensions also filtered by doctype on field
          const isFormatValid = this.formatsAllowed.includes(currentFileExt);
          const isSizeValid = file.size <= this.maxSize;
          if (isFormatValid && isSizeValid) {
            allowedFileNames.push(file.name);
            allowedFiles.push(file);
          }
        });

        return { allowedFiles, allowedFileNames };
      }
      
      /**
       * convert the data to formData for a not nested formgroup
       * "multipart/form-data" set by using formData object
       */
      getFormDataFromForm(form: FormGroup): FormData {
        const formData = new FormData();

        for (const controlName in form.controls) {
          const formControlValue = form.get(controlName).value;
          if (formControlValue instanceof Array) {
            for (const file of formControlValue) {
              formData.append(controlName, file, file.name ? file.name : '');
            }
          } else {
            formData.append(controlName, formControlValue);
          }
        }

        return formData;
      }
```

Pass the data from this.getFormDataFromForm(this.form) to the service to be submitted:

```
return this.http.post<any>(postUrl, formData, { headers }).pipe()
```

in the express you can use the multer syntax:

```
const uploadMultiField = upload.fields([{ name: 'files', maxCount: 8 }]);
router.post('/upload', uploadMultiField, (req, res) => {}
```

note: don't forget the set the "DOM.Iterable" inside your tsconfig lib entry.