# How to display images in angular from mongodb

Tags: angular

It is a very simple question for those who know angular. Since i am new to this i am struggling to get the output. I want to display image from my mongodb to my angular page. i have saved my multer images in asset folder in angular. In my books.component.ts file i am getting the books data. i am able to display my other fields except image and pdf. console log this given below.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {bookFile: {…}, bookImage: {…}, _id: '62a823f5207cbb27e6e66d06', bookName: 'King Lear', bookAuthor: 'Shakespear', …}
1: {bookFile: {…}, bookImage: {…}, _id: '62a82661207cbb27e6e66d11', bookName: 'King Lear', bookAuthor: 'Shakespear', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

this is my books.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BookdataService } from 'src/app/services/bookdata.service';
    import {BooksModel} from './books.model';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-books',
      templateUrl: './books.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
    })
    export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
      title:String = 'Book List';
      books: BooksModel[]=[];
     BookImages=[]
    
      //image properties
      // imageWidth: number=50;
      // imageMargin: number=2;
      constructor( private bookdataService: BookdataService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.bookdataService.getBooks().subscribe((data)=>{
          this.books=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log(this.books);
        })
      } 
    }
```

this is my html file

```
<tr *ngFor='let book of books'>
   <td>{{ book.bookName }}</td>
   <td>
      <img class="rounded-circle mt-5" src="../../../assets/images/{{book.bookImage}}" name="photo">
   </td>
   <td>{{ book.bookAuthor }}</td>
   <td>{{ book.bookCategory }}</td>
   <td>{{ book.bookDescription }}</td>
   <td>
      <button class="btn btn-success" style="cursor:pointer" style="margin-right: 20px;">Read</button>
   </td>
   <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" style="cursor:pointer"  style="margin-right: 20px;"> Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" style="cursor:pointer"> Delete</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and thisis my model

```
export class BooksModel{
   constructor(
       public bookName: string,
       public bookAuthor: string,
       public bookCategory: string,
       public bookDescription: string,
       public bookImage: string,
       public bookFile: string
  
   ){}
}
```

[my mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iid9t.png)
[Screenshot of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVTYG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `bookImage` is an object, and you are passing it as a string in this line

```
<img class="rounded-circle mt-5" src="../../../assets/images/{{book.bookImage}}" name="photo">
```

You should pass the identifier of the image that is *inside* the `bookImage` object instead (I don't know what that is since you left it out of your question)

**EDIT**:
Since the image data is available you have to convert it and pass it to img src.

Create a pipe create and sanitize the image urls

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'bookImageUrl' })
export class BookImageUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(book: any) {
    let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + book.bookImage.data;
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  }

}
```

Then in your html, replace the `<img>` line with this:

```
<img class="rounded-circle mt-5" [src]="book | bookImageUrl" />
```

Comment: how to do? identifier of image? please explain

Comment: that is i should put  public bookImage : {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }, in my model?

Comment: i am getting invalid url..log screenshot is updated

Comment: no need to change booksmodel.ts ri8?

Comment: did you write this line correctly?
let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + book.bookImage.data;

Comment: getImageUrl(book: any) {
    
    let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + book.bookImage.data;
  
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
}

Comment: Don't put method calls in template expression contexts, it has terrible performance. Use a pipe.

Comment: @Clashsoft you're right, i'll edit

Answer (score 0):

When you store your images in a database, the content is send as base64 encoded. You need to decode it (duh...) to get it displayed.

I can't replay exactly what you do in an example, however this is what you should have:

HMTL

```
<img id="myBookImage" [src]=thumbnail style="width: 75px" >
```

TS

```
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  public safeImage!: SafeUrl;
  thumbnail: any;
  bookImage: any;

  constructor(private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer, .....) {}

  ngOnInit(){
     // get all your books first!
     this.bookImage = booksArray[0].bookImage.data;
     this.getPicture();
  }

  getPicture() {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.bookImage);
    reader.onloadend = (() => {
       let objectURL = reader.result;
       this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('' + objectURL);
    });
  }
}
```

In your console.log you can see that bookImage is an Object and that Object contains data (the encoded image from your database).

If you want multiple images you need to do this for every book image you have using an array for instance.

Comment: books: BooksModel[]=[]; ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookdataService.getBooks().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.books=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
      console.log(this.books);
     
    }) my doubt is that.. is this way my data is fetched and saved in books.model.ts and i doubt my image data is saved in my model. if image data is not saved properly in my model.. how will i convert it to URL. my model has public bookImage:string is it correct way ??

Comment: If I look at the console log it looks like the imagedata is included. Can you go to the network tab of the console and see what's there? if there is image data included then it will show up (in Chrome Developer tools there is a Preview tab, that will show an image (if its properly encoded))

Comment: i am getting like this "failed to load response data, no data found for resource with given identifier"

Comment: Strange. Can you change ngOnInit to: ```ngOnInit(): void { this.bookdataService.getBooks().subscribe((data)=>{console.log("Step1:",data); this.books=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); console.log("Step2:",this.books); })``` and share the result from console log and the network tab please?

Comment: i have added screenshot of the console in my question..please check

Comment: any idea how will it work?

Comment: OK, the console.log shows that both bookFile and bookImage are Objects with encoded binary content. Now the next step for showing 1 image is to use the function I provided in my answer and after ```console.log("Step2"...)``` add the following code: ```this.bookImage = this.books[0].bookImage.data; this.getPicture();``` This will display 1 picture for now. Please also add the line in your HTML.

Comment: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: Can you change getPicture() to: ```getPicture() { let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.bookImage;this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('' + objectURL);
}``` This is almost the same as the second answer from Haris